# Vaadin VaadinWebSecurity & SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName

Tags: vaadin

I have a project based on Spring Boot 2.7.5 and Vaadin 23.3.0.

Using @Async methods, I'm losing the authenticated principal on upstream API calls. Researching this the solution here seems to be setting:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
```

This resolves the issue and allows for authentication data to reach threads created by a @Async function.

My question is, I see VaadinWebSecurity is setting SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName as follows:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy.class.getName());
    ...
```

I can override this in my SecurityConfig as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    ...
```

Does the above affect Vaadin's security setup at all? Is this the suggested fix for my situation or is there a better approach?

Comment: You can't change that because the VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategy uses the VaadinSession. You would need to create your own

Comment: But you could simply pass the security information you need to the async method

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks I see what you mean re VaadinSession, I've created my own SecurityContextHolderStrategy using InheritableThreadLocal instead of ThreadLocal and this seems to work fine. Would you like to post answer?

Comment: I would suggest that you post your implementation as the answer. would be helpful for otherres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Simon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simon-martinelli) recommendation, creating a new SecurityContextHolderStrategy which uses InheritableThreadLocal instead of the default ThreadLocal as follows:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolderStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

public class VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategyUsingInheritableThreadLocal implements SecurityContextHolderStrategy {

    private final InheritableThreadLocal<SecurityContext> contextHolder = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void clearContext() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public SecurityContext getContext() {
        SecurityContext context = getFromVaadinSession().orElseGet(contextHolder::get);
        if (context == null) {
            context = createEmptyContext();
            contextHolder.set(context);
        }
        return context;
    }

    @NonNull
    private Optional<SecurityContext> getFromVaadinSession() {
        VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent();
        if (session == null || session.getSession() == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        Object securityContext = session.getSession().getAttribute(
                HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
        if (securityContext instanceof SecurityContext) {
            return Optional.of((SecurityContext) securityContext);
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setContext(@NonNull SecurityContext securityContext) {
        contextHolder.set(requireNonNull(securityContext));
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public SecurityContext createEmptyContext() {
        return new SecurityContextImpl();
    }

}
```

Then applying this in my SecurityConfig after I call super.configure():

```
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(VaadinAwareSecurityContextHolderStrategyUsingInheritableThreadLocal.class.getName());
            ...
    }

    ...
```

Allows @Async methods to inherit authentication detail used in my WebClient for upstream API calls.